# Restart application in WPF

Tags: wpf, restart

The problem is that I want to restart my application to upgrade the current application. For this I am using below mentioned two lines of code.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();

Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

OR

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();

Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

But this is giving an error message of "`An unhandled win32 exception is occurred`". Hence this is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restart a WPF application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773632/how-do-i-restart-a-wpf-application)

Comment: Posting the stack trace for the exception might be a start. What is throwing that Win32 exception?

Comment: Hi Cody Gray, I have tried with [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773632/how-do-i-restart-a-wpf-application) this link. But now it is giving an error which is "An Application object is being shut down."

Comment: @user1177428 Where are you running the code? The code posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773639/302677) works fine for me, but I run it before the `base.OnStartup()` call in the `OnStartup()` method of `App.xaml.cs`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
Application.Restart();
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
Application.Exit();
```