# Application.Current.Shutdown() resets my.settings to default values

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

Hello i use the followin code to Restart my WPF application

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location)
Application.Current.Shutdown()
```

However i notice when it runs again My.Settings Values are reset to defaults, any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Are your settings application scoped or user scoped? Application scope settings are read only.

Comment: user scoped, all working fine except when i use this function they get back to defaults!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call Save() on your settings before restarting. If you do this already as part of your apps shutdown, the settings file may be locked by the new app instance, preventing the current instance from saving.

Comment: well i think that the file is locked by the old app instance, because if i run the application it loads the settings fine!

Comment: Have you tried this method of restarting? Might work better with your settings file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773632/how-do-i-restart-a-wpf-application