# Reset WPF window to its original state(startup) with a press of a button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a 'New' Button which creates a new file. On the press of 'New' button i want to reset a wpf to its original state like it was started first time. All the control should be in there start position.All the variable should be reinitialized. Consider it like a closing an application and again restarting it but, i don't want close the application. How can i achieve this in WPF?

Comment: You can [restart application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4773632/1997232) indeed, but more correct way is to provide mechanism for this. Either ViewModel (MVVM?) does this (there could be a method which reset binding sources values somehow) or you can simply recreate window.

Comment: Thanks for replay Sinatr. I will manually reset all controls as it's sound easy for few controls.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window win = new Window();
```

`win.ShowDialog();`

Try this by replacing your window name to 'Window'. Do this inside your button click event.