# How to re-initialize Prism modules?

Tags: c#, prism

I have all my modules configured in App.config and they all get initialized at run-time. However, at some point in application flow, I want to restart the GUI and also to re-initialize the modules, so when I navigate through pages, it all starts fresh. I tried call Bootstrapper.Run() at this point, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just [restart the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773632/how-do-i-restart-a-wpf-application)? All joking aside, you're probably doing something wrong if you have to re-initialize everything.

Comment: Yes, I actually want to restart the App, but not fully. I want Initialize() methods from all of my module definitions to get called again, when I click some button in my app at some point, as they get called on application startup