# Autorestart crashed WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception

I need to automatically restart my WPF when it crashes. I tried a few things now but my app still crashes and doesn't catch the error.
The second problem is I don't know why it crashes. Well I don't know the exception, VS doesn't tell me. Just vshost32.exe has stopped working. All I know is it happens if I load a lot of different files in a small amount of time in a MediaElement. (Maybe Overflow exception or something)

This is my code. It's in the App.xaml and the with "StartupUri" in the XAML removed.

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

        try
        {
            MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
            m.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }

    static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
    {
        Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
        MessageBox.Show("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
    }

    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

EDIT//
Found the exception in the errorlog of windows:
roughly translated it's this:

Anwendung: newKnoblauch.exe Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319 Description: The process has stopped because of a unhandled exception. Exceptioninfo: Exceptioncode c0000005, Exceptionadresse 55542ECC

Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: newKnoblauch.exe, Version: 1.0.0.0, Time: 0x4d62e0a6
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: wmp.dll, Version: 12.0.7600.16667, Time: 0x4c7dd593
Exceptioncode: 0xc0000005
Erroroffset: 0x00182ecc
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0xa98

Comment: Check out the answer in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225406/if-wpf-app-is-not-responding-then-auto-restart).

Comment: doesn't work at all for me.. even with "throw new ArgumentNullException();" it doesnt restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to implement auto restart, you would want to have the original executable act as a CLR host and load the target WPF application in a new AppDomain. When that AppDomain exits unexpectedly, you can repeat the process and restart the WPF app in another new AppDomain.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what it is you're doing to cause this crash, but since .Net 2, StackOverflowException can not be caught. Reference: [C# catch a stack overflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599219/c-catch-a-stack-overflow-exception)

An OutOfMemoryException would also cause unpredictable behavior. 
These are the kinds of serious exceptions that you can't really plan for. Fix the bugs that are causing them and move on. :)

Comment: found the exception. Check first post because code in comments sucks